# How to make a IF that its value is equal to the string?

Tags: android

> if text = "abc" --- then---  txt.setText=Hi

```
 TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
if(txt.setText()="text"){ 
   // do something
}
```

i mean txt equals to text

Comment: if(txt.getText().toString().equals("text"))

Comment: if(txt.getText().toString().equals("text"))  {   txt.setText("Hi");  }

Comment: Read basics of Android

Comment: just to add  : == check references of the string is e same while .equals compare string values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey and welcome to SO!

You are trying to get text with [setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) method. You need to use [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29) method. And you can't use `==` for comparing text. In java you will need to use [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare value of the object otherwise it will just compare refrence.

So for your case the code would be something like this:

```
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
if(txt.getText().toString().equals("text")){ 
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `equals()` method to compare string.

> if text = "abc" --- then--- txt.setText=Hi

```
if(text.equals("abc")){ 
     txt.setText("Hi");
}
```

Comment: change setText() to getText()

Comment: How Abou it? 
 Edit txt;
if (txt.contains("ABC")) {
            txtKey.setText("Hi");
        }

Comment: @AlexHP  what is KEYS? Is it String variable?

Comment: I was so glad it was my first question . Did not expect to be so quick answer ?

Comment: How Abou it? 
TextView txt;
if (txt.contains("ABC")) {
            txtKey.setText("Hi");
        }

Comment: @AlexHP your cann't compare textview value like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(txt.getText().toString().equals("text")){
//do something.
txt.setText("Hi");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (TextUtils.equals(txt.getText().toString(), "text")){
    txt.setText("Hi");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For preventing null pointer exception, you must put "text" in front of the variable.

```
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
if("text".equals(txt.getText().toString())){
  //do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
if(txt.getText().toString().equals("abc")){  // if txt = abc --then--
   txt.setText("Hi");                        // txt.setText=Hi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This ,

```
if(txt.getText().toString().trim().equals("text"))
{
 txt.setText("Hi");
}
```